# I want to make connection between raspberrypi as server and java desktop app as client via socket

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I want to make connection between raspberry pi and java desktop app using socket the message doesn't send  to java it comes NULL and in rpi python, it comes with an exception .what should i do?

1. server in raspberry pi

```
import socket 
import time

try:
    host=''
    port=9999
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)
    print("socket is listening..")

    while True:
        con,add=s.accept()
        print ("connect to ",add)

        messag = con.recv(1024)
        messag = messag.decode('utf-8')

        print ("messag from client ",messag)
        print ("done recive..")

        time.sleep(2)
        if not msgrecv:
            break
        #send to java 
        sendMsg = "connection..."
        sendMsg =sendMsg.encode()
        con.sendall(sendMsg)
        print ("Done send ")

        con.close()
        s.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

2. client in java

```
try {
  Socket soc = new Socket("192.168.1.4", 9999);
  DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());

  DataInputStream in =new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
  /////////////////////////////////
  while (soc.isConnected()) {

    ////////////////send
    dout.writeUTF("welecome...connect"); //wite string
    dout.flush();

    //////recive (String)
    String msg = in.readUTF();

    System.out.println("Server: " + msg);
    ///////////////

    dout.flush();

    dout.close();
    soc.close();
  }
} catch(IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

3. the output

```
Socket is Listening.... 
('connect to ', ('...',... ))
messag from Client', u'\x00\x12welecome...connect') 
done received! !! 

 connection Closed...
```

note : this is exception in python

```
exception [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

the message didn't come it come NULL
4.Error in java

```
run:
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: The posted Pi code does not produce the shown output.

Comment: `DataOutput.writeUTF(...)` does not do what you think it does. [Read the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) to see what it actually does. Same thing with `DataInput.readUTF()`